# Bootstrap 3 group-button behavior

Tags: jquery, asp.net, buttongroup

I have regular group-button behavior with label and radio buttons:

```html
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn" id="lblAct1">
    <input type="radio" value="Val1">
    Act1
  </label>
  <label class="btn" id="lblAct2">
    <input type="radio" value="Val2">
    Act2
  </label>
  <label class="btn" id="lblAct3">
    <input type="radio" value="Val3">
    Act3
  </label>
</div>
```

When I am changing title of label with `$("#lblAct1").html(getTranslation("ACT1"))` elements of button-group stops behavior as required(pressed item became active, others non-active)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because `html()` overwrites *all* content in the target element, not just the text nodes. In addition as you're dealing with text content and not HTML, you can use the `text()` method to help prevent XSS attacks.

Also note that, assuming these radio inputs are related, they need to have the same `name` attribute in order for them to be grouped correctly.

The simple fix for your situation is to place the text node within another element, for example a `span`, and then set the `text()` of that element instead:

```js
let getTranslation = input => input + ' translation here...';

$("#lblAct1 span").text(getTranslation("ACT1"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn" id="lblAct1">
    <input type="radio" value="Val1" name="foo" />
    <span>Act1</span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn" id="lblAct2">
    <input type="radio" value="Val2" name="foo" />
    <span>Act2</span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn" id="lblAct3">
    <input type="radio" value="Val3" name="foo" />
    <span>Act3</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Also note that you can make your translation code completely dynamic by providing the text of the element to the `getTranslation()` function straight from the DOM, instead of hard-coding it, and attaching N number of method calls:

```js
let getTranslation = input => input + ' translation here...';

$(".translatable span").text((i, t) => getTranslation(t))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn translatable">
    <input type="radio" value="Val1" name="foo" />
    <span>Act1</span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn translatable">
    <input type="radio" value="Val2" name="foo" />
    <span>Act2</span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn translatable">
    <input type="radio" value="Val3" name="foo" />
    <span>Act3</span>
  </label>
</div>
```